# Wildfly Swarm Consul

Tags: consul, service-discovery, wildfly-swarm

I am trying to register a Wildfly Swarm REST service to a running Consule agent, but it's not working correctly.

I am able to register a service (I can see it in the Consul ui), but somehow the health checks are not working.

The Swarm Server keeps frequently telling me, that "sending the check" failed due to "HTTP 405 Method not allowed". I can see simular logs in the Consule console, that GET method is not allowed.

I am at a dead end: My application is not working, nor does the Wildfly Swarm example (same exception). I also configured a CORS filter on both sides just to be sure, but thats not working either.

I am using Wildfly Swarm 2017.10.1 and Consul 1.0.0.

I hope you guys can help.
Best regards

Comment: Okay, I have found the concrete problem why it's not working. The Consul 1.0.0 HTTP API requires for the TTL check (/v1/agent/check/pass) a PUT method. But Wildfly Swarm is sending GET. It seems that Conul changed this with some newer version, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself. Obviously, it wasn't that hard ^^

I checked the version of the Consul Client API which is used for my Wildfly Swarm version: It's **0.9.16**. I've downloaded all Consul versions and checked which one are compatible. I can verify that all versions up to **0.9.3 are working**.

Consul 1.0.0 has some very critical breaking changes and I really don't understand why they were not implemented in a HTTP API v2, but thats not the point here.

I highly recommend to upgrade the Consul Client API used by the topology-consul fraction to a newer version like **0.16.5 or 0.17.0**.
At least, please add a note in the README for the ribbon-consul example what Consul versions can be used.